# Jar integration with jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I wrote a Java class, I made it into a runnable jar, I want to call a method in that class in a beanshell or JSR223!
I wrote a beanshell sampler, in that I imported the class and called that method, the method calls another method which has multithreading, it uses ExecutorService. 
What is happening is, the beanshell is working fine, the class is imported, the method is called, the method called another method which has threads, the problem comes when the thread is started, when the thread is started, the beanshell script is not moving further, the testcase in jmeter is not stopping at all, Is it because of threads in the class in that jar?

Comment: This is a classic case of "Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong". It very much depends on what underlying library is doing, and how it normally manages (creates/destroys) threads it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a runnable .jar it might be better idea to run it using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler). So you will be able to decide whether you want to wait till the .jar completes its work or not by using underlying operating system functionality like [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) in MS Windows Family or [`&` operator](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) or [`nohup` command](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) in Linux.

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details.

---

If you would like to continue with scripting make sure to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as currently it is the best option in terms of performance.

With regards to your "not moving further" it is hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing your Java/Beanshell code, try checking *jmeter.log* file for suspicious entries.